# How to dump a sqlite db into SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a sqlite database called `fujira.db`. I want to convert this into a SQL Server database.

I use Anaconda (Python3) and Jupyter notebook.

I've tried:

```
sqlite3 fujira.db .dump > fujira.sql
```

which throws an error:

> File "", line 1
> sqlite3 fujira.db .dump > fujira.sql
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: are typing this in a "plain terminal" (i.e. bash) or in your python terminal?

Comment: Of course this is not a valid python syntax. What is the purpose of python in this task?